# An algebra exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\sigma$ be a permutation. Prove that there exists some permutation $\rho$ such that $\sigma^{-1} = \rho \sigma \rho^{-1}$

I tried playing with it a little but to no avail.

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_type_determines_conjugacy_class

Comment: Do you know how to classify permutations up to conjugacy in terms of their cycle types?

Comment: Yes, I know that the type stays the same on conjugacy classes, so for each $\xi$ we have $type (\sigma) = type (\xi \sigma \xi^{-1})$

Comment: But i'm unable to make any use of it.